# A Kafka connector which was working is now Timing Out (Mulesoft)

Tags: apache-kafka, mule, kafka-consumer-api, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Browse operation failed; Caused by: Connection Failed;

Caused by: Unknown failure: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata; Caused by: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

```
<kafka:consumer-config name="Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration" doc:name="Apache Kafka Consumer configuration" doc:id="fc8d44ca-0fe2-4d67-944e-60484458f554" >
        <kafka:consumer-sasl-scram-connection groupId="test" username="user" password="password" encryptionType="SCRAM_SHA_512" >
            <kafka:bootstrap-servers >
                <kafka:bootstrap-server value="server:9096" />
            </kafka:bootstrap-servers>
            <kafka:topic-patterns >
                <kafka:topic-pattern value="topic" />
            </kafka:topic-patterns>
        </kafka:consumer-sasl-scram-connection>
    </kafka:consumer-config>
```

It  worked, but I don`t what could happen that the timeout exception is appearing again. I am able to connect to the topic with the same credentials trough the Kafka CLI.

Comment: consider implementing a retry mechanism so that the application retries to connect after a timeout occurs, also what are the versions of Kafka consumer and Kafka broker – maybe there's a mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Upon reviewing the provided error snippet and Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration code, pinpointing the exact cause of the issue proves challenging due to the potential for multiple error scenarios. These could include an invalid topic name, improperly configured timeout values, and various other factors.
Nevertheless, I offer the following insights to aid your debugging efforts:

1. Ensure to use the latest version of the [Mule Runtime](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-esb) and the [MuleSoft Apache Kafka connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/kafka-connector-release-notes-mule-4) to avoid any known issues.
2. To be double sure, are you able to do a successful test connection for the Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration or Is the error arising specifically during message consumption from the Topic, resulting in the "Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata" error?

Per my understanding it's the latter one, in that case, try increasing the ***Consumption Timeout*** value for the ***Consume*** operation and see what value works for your use case.

[image]

3. In addition, please make sure to have a reconnection strategy enabled (which can be found in the Apache_Kafka_Consumer_configuration ), unable to see one configured in the shared configuration.

[image]

4. Try enabling the debug logs for the [MuleSoft Apacha Kafka connector](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/DEBUG-packages-for-Anypoint-Connectors-and-modules-in-mule-4) and check what you see in the verbose logging.
5. Since the fact, this API was working fine earlier and now timing out. Worth checking with your Kafka team if any recent modifications have been made on the broker side. Investigate whether network-level restrictions or firewall changes have been introduced recently.
6. In addition, to rule out if this is a MuleSoft side issue or an issue originating from your Kafka setup, you can test using plain Java code and see how the testing goes.

Thank you!